# SOLVED - How to generate multiple QR code in one loop using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, qr-code

For example, I want to generate 10 different QR code with the same information. For now, I can generate one QR code per time only. Should I put in a loop or any solution?

```js
    function makeCode () {  

        // All inputs that contain the value
        $qrs = $('.qr_value');
        
        // Create a new instance of the QRCode for each input
        $qrs.each(function(index, item){
            
            // We cant hace same id multiple times, so, we need to create dynamic ids,
            // thats why we are concatenating the index to the id string
            let containerQr =  "qrcode_"+index;

            // Create QR
            let qrcode = new QRCode(containerQr, {
                text: item.value, // value to read on qr
                width: 500,
                height: 500,
                colorDark : "#000000",
                colorLight : "#ffffff",
                correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H,
            });
        });
    }

    makeCode();
```

```html
// loop on any technology that u use, is php on my case
foreach($values as $key => $value){
    <input type="hidden" class="qr_value" value="$value">
    <div id="qrcode_$key"></div>
}
```

Comment: Please share your code so we can have a better idea of what you have tried.

Comment: I voted to reopen to post an other answer, after comments on the other exisitng answer.

Comment: A QR Code is basically a way of encoding data. Your data is currently only the text string from the input field. You need to modify the data so it includes some unique id as well. A "clean" way IMO would be to create a JSON string containing both informations. If input text is "foo" : `"{id:1234,test:"foo"}"` You can also have this information "pasted" at the end of the string : `"foo_1234"`,

Answer (score 0):

Use a simply `for()` loop and iterate a counter wrapped around the code that generates your QR code.

```
let i = 1;
while( i <= 10){
    qrcode.clear(); // clear the code.
    qrcode.makeCode(); // make another code.
}
```

```js
for(let i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
  // generate your qr code
  console.log(i)
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for you response, but it will generate the same qr code. It is possible to generate a different qr code?

Comment: @Yumi Then there must be some information that is different, as the qrcode is just a representation (serialization) of data.

Comment: @Pac0 Oh yea. Maybe the Id is different?

Comment: What exactly determines information that differs when a code is made? This is not included in your questions information.

Comment: This is from QRCode.js yes?

Comment: Yes, it is qrcode.js